# Powershell Import-CSV outputs "@{"

Tags: powershell, import

relative newbie on PS. I have a simple CSV file:

```
Computer,Team
server,team1
server2,team2
server3,team2
```

and I wish to import this list into  PS. I use the following command, which I will use to perform queries against each computer name:

```
$Serverlist = import-csv "c:\temp\appsupportAll.txt"
$Servers = $Serverlist | Select Computer
Foreach ($Computer in $Servers)
    {etc etc}
```

The output of $Serverlist and $Servers is as I expect it. However, each $Computer is presented to PS as:

```
@{$_.Computer=server}
@{$_.Computer=server2}
@{$_.Computer=server3}
etc
```

I am looking for "server", "server2", "server3", etc. What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Computer` inside your foreach loop is not just the value you're looking for.  It is, in essence, a custom object with one property called "Computer".  If you just want the string representation of the single "Computer" property, use `select -ExpandProperty` like so:

```
$Serverlist = import-csv "c:\temp\appsupportAll.txt"
$Servers = $Serverlist | Select -ExpandProperty Computer
Foreach ($Computer in $Servers)
    {etc etc}
```

or even more simply, you can just write this:

```
$Serverlist = import-csv "c:\temp\appsupportAll.txt"
Foreach ($Computer in $serverlist.Computer)
    {etc etc}
```

or, if you need more properties:

```
$Serverlist = import-csv "c:\temp\appsupportAll.txt"

foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    $server.team
    $server.computer
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I actually should have known that as I have this done already elsewhere in the same script! Thanks a million

Comment: Accept my answer! :)

Comment: I couldn't get the "simpler" way to work though, comes up blank. I am happy with the first. I will also need to get the Team that the computer relates to

Comment: Edited to show more properties.  Strange that the second example is not working for you; it works well for me in PowerShell 5.

Comment: Just one more thing, further down my script I am trying to make a WMI connection to the registry: '$HKLM = [UInt32] "0x80000002" $WMI_Reg =WMIClass] “\\$Computer.Computer\root\default:StdRegProv” 
          $RegConnect = $True', but it doesn't like the variable in the path. It comes with the error: 'Cannot convert value "\\@{Computer=TESTWEBVIEW01; Team=App_Support}.Computer\root\d
efault:StdRegProv" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"'

Comment: Don't worry, I sorted it by creating a new variable: '$Server = [String]$Computer.Computer'

Answer (score 0):

If your input file does not have headers, use this instead:

```
 $Serverlist = Get-Content "c:\temp\appsupportAll.txt"

 $Serverlist | % {whatever you need}
```